# redirect entire website to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, web

I dont want my website to be in the root folder of my webspace!
The aim of this is to create a folder that is not accessible through the web.(eg secure files, downloads)

I've tried to redirect but I dont get it to work 100%

example:

```
-root
--downloads
--web
---f1
--.htaccess
```

my htaccess file:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L,NC]   
</ifmodule>
```

this works quite well **url.com** gets redirected to **url.com/web** without changing the url in the addressline.

but here the problems start
as soon as i try to access a folder like **url.com/f1** it gets redirected to (and displayed as) **url.com/web/f1**, what i dont want to be shown in the addressline.

furthermore i still can access **url.com/downloads** which i expected to be redirected to **url.com/web/downloads**

can someone please explain to me hot to fix this, or what is the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: Shouldn't `downloads` or `f1` etc folders be under `web/`?

Answer (score 0):

> The aim of this is to create a folder that is not accessible through
>   the web.(eg secure files, downloads)

So for you first problem, you need to move your folders *outside* of the root. That's the best way to make them secure. With a structure like this.

```
--downloads
--f1
--root
  -- web
```

Then there is absolute no way they can reach it within the browser and you don't need rewriterules for this.

Now you can just use your backend code to retrieve the file and then allow user to download it if they are authorized. You didn't say what you were using so, I'll provide a PHP example.

You can then use code like this to force download. You can use the link below for full example and also using DB.

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0); // disable the time limit for this script

$path = "/home/username/downloads/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure

$dl_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file']); // simple file name validation
$dl_file = filter_var($dl_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); // Remove (more) invalid characters
$fullPath = $path.$dl_file;

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a file download
        break;
        // add more headers for other content types here
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
```

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/php-download-file-script/